# Get up to full speed

Tags: train-simulator-2015

I'm doing the scenario "In a hurry" on TS2015 but can't get the train above 102 MPH meaning I'm already late by the time I get to the first stop. I've seen videos of people getting up more speed than that, so am very confused as to what I need to do to get there on time!

Comment: Which train is used in this scenario?

Comment: Can you describe the scenario? What train on what route?